# File grabber from FTP

Tags: java, html, ftp

I have a file that changes every day for my website and I want to make a program that takes it from the FTP server and either downloads it to my phone or my laptop.

How would I go about making this and what code do I use?

Comment: What kind of a file is it?  Does it have to be fetched from FTP or could it be fetched over HTTP?

Comment: @Moose it is a .txt file and it register users who log in to my ftp server with my hosting service so I'm guessing from there?

Comment: if you go to the txt file in your web browser, can you see the file?  I am trying to see if there is a strict requirement for you to have to do it through FTP instead of HTTP before I give you any advice.

Comment: @moose if I go to the file manager I can see it but it is not accessible by the website

Comment: okay, so it sounds like you have to do it over FTP.  From the tags you added on this post I am guessing you will have to use Java.  Im not a Java developer but I know that there are libraries in Java that allow you to FTP and download files (you can do a quick Google search to find one that is appropriate for you).  Find the library and use it with your FTP credentials.  Download the file then parse it the way you need to.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs//

Comment: @moose I only used java tag because I thought that is what it might have to be if you have any alternative code I am very open to hearing it

Comment: well, doing a quick search online i found that PHP has a function called `ftp_get`, here is the manual page for it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php . 

This seems like it would work because if you look at the example on that page, it shows that you can use your FTP credentials to access the server.

Comment: @moose thanks for the help I will do this tomorrow while I'm at my work computer

Answer (score 0):

A few options not already mentioned:

- If you have access to the ftp server, a cron job could email the file to you each day.
- You could create a web page populated with the data, using jsp, php, or servlet etc. to read the file from disk.
- If you're familiar with rsync, you could simply rsync the file to your laptop
- Sync the file using Dropbox